# Changes to JavaScript files do not take effect instantly. Possible issue with gulp browserify task

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, gulp, browserify

When I make changes to a JavaScript file it often takes up to 10 seconds of constantly refreshing the page before the changes take effect. I know that Chrome caches a lot, and I have used a couple of techniques to work around this:

I have set the Cache-control header to 'no-cache, no-store', added a query string based on the current time to every javascript file (and I have confirmed that this actually changes every time I refresh), and I have enabled the "Disable cache" option in the dev tools. However, the JavaScript files still don't load instantly...

Edit: 
After some more testing I have discovered that the gulp browserify task in my node.js app (that builds client-side JavaScript bundles) not updates the builds before 5-10 seconds after gulp has restarted. This is however weird since gulp outputs "Finished 'browserify' after 3.24 ms". This explains why the JavaScript files don't refresh in the browser, but I'm not able to figure out why they are not refreshed immediately.

Have anyone experienced this before?

Comment: since you tagged node.js, are you talking about client-side or server-side javascript files? (guessing client-side but just to be sure)

Comment: I'm talking about client-side javascript files. The node.js tag was used because the server that generates the javascript files (through browserify) runs node. Should perhaps have specified this in the question details

Comment: are you generating those files on the fly? (as in, everytime you change them?)

Comment: I have a gulp browserify task that is supposed to build JavaScript bundles every time I save, yes. After looking into it now, it seems like the bundles aren't build immediately after gulp is run. It takes about 5-10 seconds before the files in the file system refreshes. However, gulp reports "Finished 'browserify' after 3.24 ms". So this might actually be a gulp/browserfiy issue. Still not able to figure it out though..

Comment: I'm not familiar with gulp but you might wanna change your question and tag accordingly or open a new one to attract the right audience for it then

Comment: What does your `browserify` gulp task look like? How big is the project you are compiling? Do you have any third-party browserify transforms installed?

Comment: It looks pretty much like this: https://github.com/eiriklv/express-passport-app/blob/master/gulp/tasks/browserify.js. I have the hbsfy and envify transforms installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task finishes before browserify is done because it's not set up correctly, probably you're not returning the stream.

Browserify takes a while to build files, definitely not a few milliseconds, so while gulp reports it as done, browserify is still working on it and saves the file 5-10 seconds later.

Look into [gulp-starter](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter) to see how it uses watchify to considerably speed up compilation time during development.

Answer (score 0):

Open Developer Console -> Go to Network Tab -> Click on Disable Cache checkbox on the top..

[image]

Comment: That means you still need to refresh for 10 to 15 times ?

Comment: Yes, still need to refresh constantly for at least 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for most of today. Tried everything from disabling cache in Chrome dev-tools, to rebooting everything from gulp to browser to laptop (I had a feeling it was a cache/memory thing as Gulp had been working perfectly for a long time before today)

Finally decided to uninstall and reinstall my global Gulp package. Not only does the problem seem to have been solved but starting the Gulp watchify process seems much faster now as well. I'd suggest giving this a try